# How to fetch records from DB which fulfill a certain criteria

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following problem and wanted to ask if this is the correct way to do it or if there is a better way of doing it:

Assume I have the following table/data in my DB:

```
|---|----|------|-------------|---------|---------|
|id |city|street|street_number|lastname |firstname|
|---|----|------|-------------|---------|---------|
| 1 | ar | K1   |    13       |Davenport| Hector  |
| 2 | ar | L1   |    27       |Cannon   | Teresa  |
| 3 | ar | A1   |    135      |Brewer   | Izaac   |
| 4 | dc | A2   |    8        |Fowler   | Milan   |
| 5 | fr | C1   |    18       |Kaiser   | Ibrar   |
| 6 | fr | C1   |    28       |Weaver   | Kiri    |
| 7 | ny | O1   |    37       |Petersen | Derrick |
```

I now get some some requests of the following structures: (city/street/street_number)

E.g.: `{(ar,K1,13),(dc,A2,8),(ny,01,37)}`

I want to retrieve the last name of the person living there. Since the request amount is quite large I don't want to run over all the request one-by-one. My current implementation is to insert the data into a temporary table and join the values.

Is this the right approach or is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: Your approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a query using `in` with tuples:

```
select t.*
from t
where (city, street, street_number) in ( (('ar', 'K1', '13'), ('dc', 'A2', '8'), ('ny', '01', '37') );
```

However, if the data starts in the database, then a temporary table or subquery is better than bringing the results back to the application and constructing such a query.

Comment: The data does not start in the database, but I have around 80.000 request, which is not possible to do with in clauses since for example Oracle limits them to 1.000. (The table in production also has around 560.000 entries which I think again will not work so well with in-clauses)

Comment: @StephanStahlmann . . . As I say, your approach with a temporary table is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the hierarchy query and string function as follows:

```
WITH YOUR_INPUT_DATA AS
(SELECT '(ar,K1,13),(dc,A2,8),(ny,01,37)' AS INPUT_STR FROM DUAL),
--
CTE AS
( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^,]',1,2) AS STR1, 
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^,]',1,3) AS STR2, 
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'[^,]',1,4) AS STR3
   FROM  (SELECT SUBSTR(INPUT_STR, 
              INSTR(INPUT_STR,'(',1,LEVEL), 
              INSTR(INPUT_STR,')',1,LEVEL) - INSTR(INPUT_STR,'(',1,LEVEL) + 1) STR
  FROM YOUR_INPUT_DATA
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(INPUT_STR,'\),\(') + 1))
--
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE (city,street,street_number)
IN (SELECT STR1,STR2,STR3 FROM CTE);
```